# jQuery code to delay JavaScript execution until page load causes JS to throw runtime error

Tags: javascript, jquery, document-ready

#### The Setting:

I coded some JavaScript to dynamically populate a table with data and then listen for a click event on any of that data, upon which it dynamically populates and displays a modal dialog with information about the clicked data. See the [/test-table](http://www.familyhistoryconferencenwa.org/test-table) page of my site and the pen [Table Play](http://codepen.io/alxfyv/pen/yJJbXr) at CodePen. And up to this point, everything is jake, just hunky-dory.

Now I need to put all the JS in the `<head>` of the page with the table. But the JS manipulates the DOM, so I have to delay execution until the page loads. I've found answers to that issue which say to wrap the JS in the jQuery statement:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // ... js code here ...
});
```

or in

```
$(window).bind('load', function() {
  // ... js code here ...
});
```

#### The Problem:

That, however, causes the JS to throw a runtime error.

When testing it locally on my system, the error is "Uncaught ReferenceError: classes is not defined." When testing it in the pen [Table Play](http://codepen.io/alxfyv/pen/yJJbXr), it's "Uncaught ReferenceError: removePopup is not defined." Classes is the array of objects from which the JS populates the table. RemovePopup is the function invoked when the modal dialog's dismiss button is clicked.

**Edit 0:**

The [TablePlay](http://codepen.io/alxfyv/pen/yJJbXr) base code is without the jQ. When I put the code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

at JS line 1 and the code

```
});
```

at JS line 316 (the last line), then click on a table cell item, then click the modal dialog's dismiss button, the "removePopup not defined" error logs to the console. See this [screenshot](http://take.ms/cEKcix).

The removePopup function is set as the dismiss button's onclick function at JS line 190. It is defined beginning at JS line 92. As to the line at which the error is occurring, the console message simply says "onclick @ index.html?editors=0010:formatted:1".

**End Edit 0**

The error only occurs upon wrapping the JS in either of the jQ statements. And the JS in the pen and locally on my system are the same, the former copied and pasted from the latter, so one would expect any error to be the same.

#### The Question(s):

Does anyone have an inkling what might be going on?

Why would wrapping otherwise correct JS in one of these jQ statements cause an "undefined" error, and why would it be the variable classes on my system and the function removePopup in the pen?

More importantly, of course, how do I delay the execution of the JS until the DOM has fully loaded?

Comment: I am not able to replicate the error in codepen.Also please mention at which line you are ssing the error

Comment: Have you moved previously global function or variable declarations into your document ready handler but continued trying to reference them from other code that isn't in the ready handler? If *all* of your JS is inside a single document ready handler then there should be no reference problems. (To answer your final question on how to delay execution, you either use a document ready handler appropriately or move your script to the end of the body.)

Comment: @user2181397 I edited the post to give the information you requested as best I can. I also indicated how it is I get the error message in the pen and left a link to a screenshot. Thanks for your interest. I hope I've provided the info you need.

Comment: @ nnnnnn Thank you for your comment and interest. I double checked. All variable and function declarations are within the document-ready handler. There are no references to any of them outside the handler. There is no JS code of any kind outside the handler. All JS code is in a single .js file loaded in the HTML document head with '<script type="..." src="..."></script>` tags after the `<script></script>` that loads the jQuery. Ditto for the pen [Table Play](http://codepen.io/alxfyv/pen/oLLeRX).

Comment: @ nnnnnn (continued ...)  In the Squarespace site I built, the closest I can come to putting the JS at the end of the body is to put it in the site-wide footer. But I don't want it site-wide, just on the one page with the table. I only have access to its page header code injection and script there runs before the DOM is fully loaded. That;s why I need to delay JS execution.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I've not yet determined what it is that's causing the function undefined error, but I've found an alternate implementation that works.

Instead of using the jQuery document ready handler, I added

```
window.onload = function() {
  init();
};
```

to the script in the document head. I defined init() to declare and initialize the global variables, to populate the table with its data, and to add the click event listeners.

Thanks to the commenters for their interest and time with a particular thanks to @nnnnnn for his/her remark about my possibly having

> moved previously global function or variable declarations into your document ready handler but continued trying to reference them from other code that isn't in the ready handler.

Although I couldn't see where I might have done that, it made think of this alternative approach as a way to avoid that happening.